# Concurrent update in table "SYS": h2 database fails while inserting multiple records

Tags: java, database, h2

I encountered an error below with h2 database 1.4.197. Basically, I am trying to update the record as soon as it is being processed.

Instead of insert, I am using merge statement as I don't want duplicate records. Below is my query:

`merge into tableName key(col1,col2) values(?,?,?);`

I am using connection pooling with maximum connection pool set to 100 and from debugging, I identified that the error is thrown on random order. Having said that, error was first thrown when 1000th record was being inserted. On second execution, it happened with 554th record.

Here is my connectionstring:

`jdbc:h2:file:" + DB_NAME + ";MV_STORE=true;MVCC=true;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`

Below is the stacktrace.

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path" [50000-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:307)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.toSQLException(DbException.java:280)
    at org.h2.message.TraceObject.logAndConvert(TraceObject.java:357)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:268)
    at com.verscend.dxcg.reports.db.h2.QueryHelper.insertOrUpdateTable(QueryHelper.java:20)
    at com.verscend.dxcg.audit.AuditLogGenerator.process(AuditLogGenerator.java:22)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:298)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:207)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected code path
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:254)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:267)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.unlockAll(Session.java:985)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.endTransaction(Session.java:760)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.commit(Session.java:708)
    at org.h2.command.Command.stop(Command.java:157)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.stop(CommandContainer.java:122)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:296)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:249)
    ... 23 more

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Concurrent update in table "SYS": another transaction has updated or deleted the same row [90131-197]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:357)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.removeRow(RegularTable.java:375)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.removeMeta(Database.java:985)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.updateMeta(Database.java:1698)
    at org.h2.command.ddl.Analyze.analyzeTable(Analyze.java:136)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.commit(Session.java:701)
    at org.h2.command.Command.stop(Command.java:157)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.stop(CommandContainer.java:122)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:296)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.execute(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:249)
    at com.verscend.dxcg.reports.db.h2.QueryHelper.insertOrUpdateTable(QueryHelper.java:20)
    at com.verscend.dxcg.audit.AuditLogGenerator.process(AuditLogGenerator.java:22)
    at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:103)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:145)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:120)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:541)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.sendToConsumers(SedaConsumer.java:298)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.doRun(SedaConsumer.java:207)
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaConsumer.run(SedaConsumer.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

`
What am i missing here?

Comment: I'm encountering a similar issue. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with the same version (1.4.197) and I am using a single database connection where I insert a lot of records using a single, reused PreparedStatement. The insert uses a standard insert SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary workaround for this problem:

If an exception is thrown when inserting a record (it happens only every 5-10.000 records or so, seemingly randomly), the thread waits 10 milliseconds, and then retries to insert the record. If the retry also fails, the exception is propagated up, and the record not inserted.

So far, the wait-and-retry seems to give the database enough time to unlock the record in question.